# number of points needed to check if a special polynomial remainder is zero

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, chinese-remainder-theorem, groebner-basis

We know $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ with integer coefficients and degree of $x$ and $y$ less than or equal to two:

$f(x,y)=\sum_{i,j\epsilon \left \{ 0,1,2 \right \}}a_{ij}x^i y^j$

where $a_{ij}$'s are integers. We are interested to check whether $a_{00}+a_{02}+a_{20}+a_{22}=0$ by evaluating $f$ at some points in the $xy$ plane.

One solution to that is to evaluate $f$ at following four points $(1,1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (-1,-1)$ then check if $ S = f(1,1)+f(1,-1)+f(-1,1)+f(-1,-1)$ is zero or not. It is easy to show that $S = 4(a_{00}+a_{02}+a_{20}+a_{22})$.
The question is whether or not we could check if $S=0$ by evaluating $f(x,y)$ at fewer points (i.e. 3 points or fewer)?

What if the coefficients are not integers and/or we are using a computer with limited arithmetic precision to do all the computations.

Note that $a_{00}+a_{02}+a_{20}+a_{22}$ is the remainder of $f(x,y)$ divided by $(x^2-1), (y^2-1), x, y$. or in other words it equals to $f(x,y)$ when $ x^2\to1, x\to0, y^2\to1, y\to0$. (not sure if these would help)

Comment: As currently posed, it is not true that $S=4(a_{00}+a_{22})$. Consider $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$: this gives $S=8$, but $a_{00}+a_{22}=0$.

Comment: @KReiser Sorry I had missed two terms. I fixed the problem description now.

Comment: I guess you aren't interested in "cheat" solutions such as calculating $f(\root3\of2,\root3\of3)$ alone? Given that the coefficients are integers that value determines $f$ uniquely, and thus allows us to check any property of $f$ :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That is in fact good point. But is there none "cheat" solutions with fewer than 4 points? Let's add the constraint that we are using a computer with limited arithmetic precision to do the computations.  Or even relax the constraint that the coefficients are integers.  Would 4 points be the minimum number then? Is there a systematic way to solve such problems (eg. find the number of points needed and the points?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we ignore the possibilities that a single value of $f$ could yield information about several linear combinations of the coefficients by virtue of that value being calculated at an extension field of the field of coefficients (see my comment under the OP) ...

> You need to calculate the value of $f$ at **four** points to be able to figure out the sum $a_{00}+a_{02}+a_{20}+a_{22}.$

This can be shown as follows. Assume contrariwise that knowing $f(P_i)$ at three points $P_i=(x_i,y_i), i=1,2,3,$ would suffice. Clearly we then have
a relation of the form
$$
a_{00}+a_{02}+a_{20}+a_{22}=a_1f(P_1)+a_2f(P_2)+a_3f(P_3)
$$
that holds for some coefficients $a_i,i=1,2,3$, and all $f$ (we need the assumption that we are working over an infinite, or at least a large enough field to justify this step).
For this to work we would need to be able to express the last row of the matrix
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & y_1 & y_1 x_1 & y_1x_1^2 & y_1^2 & y_1^2x_1 & y_1^2x_1\\
 1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & y_2 & y_2 x_2 & y_2x_2^2 & y_2^2 & y_2^2x_2 & y_2^2x_2\\
 1 & x_3 & x_3^2 & y_3 & y_3 x_3 & y_3x_3^2 & y_3^2 & y_3^2x_3 & y_3^2x_3\\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
as a linear combination of the top three rows.

Let us first consider the case where $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are all distinct. In that case the top left $3\times 3$ corner in $A$ is invertible as a Vandermonde matrix. This means that there are *unique* coefficients $a_1,a_2,a_3$ such that
$$
a_1(1,x_1,x_1^2)+a_2(1,x_2,x_2^2)+a_3(1,x_3,x_3^2)=(1,0,1).
$$
Looking at the next three columns we then see that we must also have
$$
a_1y_1(1,x_1,x_1^2)+a_2y_2(1,x_2,x_2^2)+a_3y_3(1,x_3,x_3^2)=(0,0,0).
$$
By linear dependence we thus deduce that $a_iy_i=0$ for all $i$.
Similarly the last three columns imply that $a_iy_i^2=a_i$ for all $i$. So whenever $a_i\neq0$ we must have both $y_i=0$ and $y_i^2=1$. This forces all the $a_i$s to vanish which is a contradiction.

Assume then that there are repetitions among the $x$-coordinates. Without loss of generality we can assume that $x_3=x_1$. Clearly then $x_1\neq x_2$ as otherwise the three first columns already give a contradiction. Again, the linear independence of $(1,x_1,x_1^2)$ and
$(1,x_2,x_2^2)$ and looking at the columns in groups of three as above imply that
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_1+a_3&=a_1y_1^2+a_3y_3^2\\
a_2&=a_2y_2^2\\
a_1y_1+a_3y_3&=0\\
a_2y_2&=0.
\end{aligned}
$$
Again we get a contradictiion, because $a_2\neq0$, $a_2y_2=0$, $a_2y_2^2=a_2$.

Looks like this is generalizable, but I'm afraid I don't know exactly how.

Comment: Well, what if we use modular arithmetic? Intuitively based on your comment, I assume, if we assign some values to x and y, then apply chinese remainder theorem we may be able to test it with fewer than four points. We could for example also apply a change of variables such as $x' = (x+1)/2$ and $y'=(y+1)/2$ to facilitate that. In that case we need to assign values to x and y where $x^2 = x $ mod p. Would that work?

Comment: @mghandi I guess that something like that might work if the coefficients are bounded to some interval. Then evaluating at a point with large coordinates could be used to "cheat".

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x,y)=x^2$, then $a_{0,0}+a_{2,2}=0$ but
$$f(1,1)+f(-1,1)+f(1,-1)+f(-1,-1)=4\ne0.$$

Now
$$f(2,2)-4f(1,1)+6f(0,0)-4f(-1,-1)+f(-2,-2)=24a_{2,2}$$
and $f(0,0)=a_{0,0}$ so one can check that $a_{0,0}+a_{2,2}=0$
by evaluating at five points. I don't know if that is optimal.

Comment: The correct question is that we want to check if $a_{00}+a_{02}+a_{20}+a_{22} =0$. sorry for the confusion.